# Create a function that returns a given string in descending(NOT REVERSE) order

Tags: python, string, comparison, character

I had this question on my final and I couldn't figure it out. I originally tried using a for i in range(len(string)-1) loop to compare the numerical value of the characters in the indexes.

I know I can just use a list sort the list then print it in reverse but we were told we can't use lists or the reverse and sort functions.

Also can't use the print(string[ : :-1]) technique because this isn't about reversing a string it's about putting it into descending order. For example, the string, "Hello" would have an output of, "ollhe" not "olleh" and the string, "world" would output, "wrold" not "dlrow"

If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Do you need to print the string in descending alphabetical order?

Comment: How about `"".join(sorted(x.lower())[::-1])`

Comment: @WilliamZ From what I understand in the question, he isn't supposed to use [::-1]

Comment: @LucaGiorgi I thought they were just clarifying that they didn't merely want the reverse of the string

Comment: @WilliamZ you're probably right, but I just noticed he isn't supposed to use the sort functions either

Comment: @LucaGiorgi ah, I missed that

Comment: "`"world"` would output, `"wlord"`" -- are you sure that's descending alphabetical order?

Comment: They probably don't want this answer, but counting sort: `import collections; letters = collections.Counter(input); return ''.join(chr(idx) * letters[chr(idx)] for idx in xrange(ord(max(letters.keys())), 0, -1))`

Comment: my mistake on the "world" output, it should be "wrold" thanks for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following with several strings as `st`.

```
def finalexamquestion(st):
    st = st.lower()
    max = 'a'
    result = ""
    for j in range(len(st)):
        for i in range(len(st)):
            if st[i] >= max:
                max = st[i]
                idx = i
        st = st[:idx]+st[idx+1:]
        result += max
        max = 'a'
#    print result
    return result
```

Using ASCII values of characters to find max values (later in alphabet) in string. That is basically a sorting function that working on string and sorting chars. You can implement a better sorting algorithm such as QuickSort (my implementation is working with O(n^2)). There are better algorithms with O(nlogn) but it is not the point here so I implement it with that one.

For every char in string, finds max and removes it from the string.

Comment: works in python 2.x. May need some changes (indentation) in python 3.x

Comment: this will work in 3.x without any changes.. (except for print, but its commented out anyway)

Comment: The only thing I would add is the case where there are capital letters in st. There are a couple ways of handling this, you could add a `st = st.lower()` command before processing then the capital letters would get processed as normal letters, or anywhere you have `st[i]` use `ord(st[i])`, set your `max = 0` and use `result += chr(max)`, then the capitals would be sorted on their own after the lowercase letters.

Comment: @DustinPianalto thanks, i will edit the answer with your addition.

Comment: Thanks! this looks like the way I needed my code to be. I had it similar to yours but I didn't have the nested for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether the function is supposed to work only on alphabet letters or punctuation (and space) as well, so I will assume only the 26 letters of the alphabet. An extension of this, however, is straightforward.

```
def descent_alphabetically(word):
    # Lazy way of constructing 'zyxw...dcba'
    alphabet = ''.join(chr(i) for i in xrange(122, 96, -1))
    word = word.lower()
    return ''.join(letter * word.count(letter) for letter in alphabet)
```

The idea is you go through the letters of the alphabet in reverse order and count how many are in your word. If the count is 0, the string multiplication will be empty, while, for example, if you have the letter 'a' three, you'll get 'aaa'.

You said lists are allowed. I don't know whether that would also extend to `range()`, since it produces a list. But you can always hardcode the "symbols" of your alphabet in the reverse order you want them to appear. And since lists aren't allowed, does this also mean list/generator comprehensions aren't either? You can avoid this by changing the syntax to:

```
result = ''
for letter in alphabet:
    result += letter * word.count(letter)
```

**Examples**

```
descent_alphabetically('Hello')
'ollhe'
>>> descent_alphabetically('world')
'wrold'
>>> descent_alphabetically('alphabet')
'tplhebaa'
```